# Monary import error

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, anaconda

I am trying to test out MongoDB using the speedy and sexy Monary package I've been reading about. I've tried a pip and manual install on my windows 7 64bit machine with the Anaconda 64bit python stack installed and get the following error:

```
C:\Users\cpye\Desktop\Monary-0.2.3.tar\dist\Monary-0.2.3\Monary-0.2.3>python
Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:40:02) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import monary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "monary\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .monary import Monary
  File "monary\monary.py", line 33, in <module>
    _load_cmonary_lib()
  File "monary\monary.py", line 31, in _load_cmonary_lib
    cmonary = CDLL(cmonaryfile)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
>>>
```

The setup goes through just fine once I sorted out MinGW and gcc issues. I'm not sure what is getting called that "is not a valid Win32 application" any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means that you are mixing 64-bit and 32-bit executables.  Perhaps try using the 32-bit version of Anaconda.